# Convert Time series Events into Alarm on and Alarm off pair

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a single table of both Safety related alarm and normal equipment alarm. these alarm are getting logged. The table looks like

```
   Name                        record     Timestamp
S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    1   19-11-2020 06:22:53
S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR1   1   19-11-2020 06:22:53
S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    0   19-11-2020 06:22:55
S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR1   0   19-11-2020 06:22:55
S304R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    1   19-11-2020 07:05:28
S304R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    0   19-11-2020 07:05:30
```

For safety related tag; if record=0, alarm is on and record=1, alarm is off (condition1)
for Normal equipment tag; if record=1, alarm is on and record=0, alarm is off (condition2)

What I am trying to get is

```
        Name                              intime                   outtime 
    S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    19-11-2020 06:22:53   19-11-2020 06:22:55
    S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR1   19-11-2020 06:22:53   19-11-2020 06:22:55
    S304R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    19-11-2020 07:05:28   19-11-2020 07:05:30
    S302R1_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR    19-11-2020 08:07:08   19-11-2020 08:07:15
```

I have a list of normal equipment tags. If this tag name is available in list, alarm on/off pair should be formed on condition 2 or else alarm on/off should be based on condition 1.

Note: this becomes tricky when the Equip is switched off and on. All the equip tag will gets initialized with value 0 and safety tag with 1.

Attached data set link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/19NIm_WWJDqSOUDc3O5G9pFW2InsQ4GOT/view

Normal equip tag link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UFFT-m4j6xlzKVQk8qjjsrZuQj6jJwSG/view

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: i need solution whether i get it for MS SQL or posrtgresql doesnot matter.  both will be useful to me

Comment: Then choose one, as both use different dialects. Alsosl please don't post links to Google drive file for others to download; as professionals we know the dangers of downloading files from unknown sources. If the information bis important, include it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can make this work with [`LEAD()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html):

```sql
WITH ordered_data as
(
   SELECT *
   ,LEAD(td.Timestamp,1,NULL)OVER(PARTITION BY td.Name ORDER by td.Timestamp) next_event
   FROM table_data td
)
--Normal equipment tags
SELECT Name,Timestamp intime, next_event outtime
FROM ordered_data
WHERE record = 1
AND Name IN ('S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR','S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR1') --add all names here or do a subselect if you have the list
UNION 
--safety related tags
SELECT Name,Timestamp intime, next_event outtime
FROM ordered_data
WHERE record = 0
AND Name NOT IN ('S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR','S303R2_LS_STN_ATD_SENSOR_ERR1') --add all names here or do a subselect if you have the list
```

Comment: can you please explain me what is happening here in this code if possible

Comment: Yes - LEAD()` calculates the next timestamp per td.Name. In case it's a record=1 it should be a record=0 and vice versa. The part above the UNION handles the condition 2 (normal equipment), the part below the UNIOn handles the condition 1 safety tags...